# Do not maintain session

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have one website and i have added it in bookmark.

the situation is:
i opened the browser and website loaded from bookmarked location now the tab1 contains the website next i am logging it now it is in home page.

then i opened new tab but i didnt loaded any site. then i closed the tab1 then i opening the site from bookmark location. here instead of loginpage its directly loading the page which was in tab2.

when i can close the logged in tab then it should ask for login page in next tab

please help me guys how to achieve this

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Login cookie is shared in same browser tabs (sometimes even in same type of browser).

In other words, if you login in a tab in IE, you do not have to login in different tabs. Login cookie is still valid, and you are automatically login.

However, if you open same page in FireFox or Chrome, you'll still have to login even if you have logged-in in IE.

**Updated:** Please do not ask user to re-login if a tab is closed and reopen in different tab (in same browser). Even banking websites won't do that. (Of course, user'll need to relogin if the browser is closed.)

Comment: Is this ansewer the question??

Comment: What I'm trying to say is - you shouldn't ask user to re-login if closing tab and reopening in different tab (in same browser windows). It is an expected behavior, and even banking websites won't do that.

Comment: Really, let me know that bank :D

Comment: Bank of America, City Bank. Come on huMphy. Closing tab and closing browser is totally different. We all expect to relogin if we close the browser, but not tab.

Comment: Most of the banks website DO NOT share login cookie between tabs. I just verified BoA, CITI in Chrome/IE.

Comment: Ok. Open a couple of tabs in your browser. Login to https://safe.bankofamerica.com/myaccounts/details/deposit/account-details.go and close the tab (do not close your browser). Then past that url again in new tab. It won't ask you to relogin again since your authentication cookie is still valid. Same for citi bank - https://www.accountonline.com/cards/svc/AccountActivity.do

Comment: @Win if we copy and paste the URL in a new tab it will work. I'm sure it also work even if we paste the URL in new browser window. i'm expecting it to work like gmail does. (If you logged in to gmail in one tab and entering gmail.com in new tab/browser will bring your mail without a prompt for id/pwd.

Comment: @Aishu - you are missing my point. We all know that cookie is stored by the domain; you can't read cross site cookie. As long as you are logged-in to a site, and access the same site in different tab (same browser), you shouldn't be asked to relogin again. Original question is Mukesh wants logged-in user to relogin again in different tab. My answer is do not ask user to relogin in different tab (in same browser window); ask to relogin only if user closed the browser or logout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to logged out the user when page is closing.

You can use `onbeforeunload` event to manually logged out the active user.

Have a look at this article about [Save Changes on Close of Browser or When Exiting the Page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20260/Save-Changes-on-Close-of-Browser-or-When-Exiting-t)